# BUILD FAILED error while trying to build FBReaderJ(https://github.com/geometer/FBReaderJ)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, android-ndk

The process to build FBReaderJ

> 1. Create 'local.properties' file containing sdk.dir && ndk.dir
>      definitions: sdk.dir= ndk.dir= E.g., on my computer
>      'local.properties' consists of 2 lines:
>      sdk.dir=/Users/geometer/android-sdk-mac_86
>      ndk.dir=/Users/geometer/android-ndk-r4b
> 2. If you use Linux or MacOS, just run 'ant package' or 'ant release' and go to step 3. 
>          If you are windows user,
>
>    2a. Run ndk-build (a program from Android NDK directory) in your
>      project catalog; This program only runs from Cygwin >= 1.7, please
>      read NDK docs for details.
>
>    2b. Run ./createRawResources.py script.
>
>    2c. Run 'ant release'
> 3. Sign your package manually.

The error I get after running ant package:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140624/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:577: ${google.services.lib.dir} resolve to a path with no project.properties file for project /Users/rupeshparab/Documents/workspace/FBReaderJ-master

Total time: 9 seconds
```

Note: I am trying it on OS X

Comment: What is and where is createRawResources.py ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ant package won't work as there is no file with name package, try ant release, and the error you have shown after ant release seems to be related to sdk, where there might be some issues with your google services api

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, you are right ant release works. But I have installed everything from the SDK manager, don't know which component is needed specifically.